# imessage extension not showing icon xcode ios

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, imessage

I have assigned all the icon size according to apple's guidance about the iMessage extension icon. but the imessage extension won't show the app icon

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's just a temporary thing. After some reinstalls or simulator-restarts, it'll show. May be it's some kind of bug in X-Code/Simulator.

Comment: Has test this thousand of times, nothing happens, and the extension was actually added by Unity post-build script and the image assets were copied there, but when building with the Xcode (adding target), things will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the example project provided by apple https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages/icecreambuilder_building_an_imessage_extension

You need to create app icon assets under the app as well as the messages extension directory.